# UIImageView over UIButton does not appear in iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a wired problem !!!
I have a UIImageView over UIButton done by interface builder. the case is the UIImageView appear on iPhone 5 and doesn't appear on iPhone 4 !!

What is the problem ??? !!!!

provided pictures for the application

*** Running iOS Version : 7.1.1

IB : 
[image]

iPhone 5 :
[image]

iphone 4 :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Size inspector in the XCode right menu:

[image]

And make sure that the `Autoresizing` is correct.

Any way, to check yourself and switch to iPhone 4/5 in the `Simulated Metrics`:

[image]